Ubuntu XFCE options to emulate Windows Color Filter Grayscale
I am looking to see if there are any options outside of Gnome plugins to achieve some color filters to protect my eyes during evening laptop sessions.
I  have attempted using a redshift config and xcalib to see if i can atleast get something easier on the eyes. It's a bit not the best :).
xcalib -d :0 /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5000K.icc

cat ~/.config/redshift.conf
[redshift]
location-provider=manual
day-night=6500k
temp-night=3500k

brightness=0.9  
gamma=0.8:0.8:0.8  # Adjust gamma to desaturate further (same for R, G, B)

[manual]
lat=44
lon=25


Try: https://depo.pardus.org.tr/pardus/pool/main/p/pardus-night-light/pardus-night-light_0.2.1_all.deb

That does help test a lot in tweaking with the slider to get a better in the moment profile. Was just hoping there is some other combination to achieve closer to grayscale.
